# Entity Framework SaveChanges() not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, xml-serialization

I am practicing with wcf and entity framework. In my situation I have two wcf services, one for the read operations, and one for the crud operations. In my front end I am using C# forms. I have taken a record from the wcf service reference for reading, made some modifications and persisting it to the DB through the wcf crud service. I receive a true response from the operation, that shows that it do not throw any errors, but the changes are not saved in the db. I am using adventure works for tests.

CRUD wcf:

```
public class AWCRUD : IAWCRUD
{
    public bool updatePerson(Person person)
    {
        try
        {
            using (AWEntities ctx = new AWEntities())
            {
                ctx.People.Attach(person);
                ctx.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool updateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        try
        {
            using (AWEntities ctx = new AWEntities())
            {
                ctx.Employees.Attach(employee);
                ctx.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

READ wcf:

```
public class WCFAWRead : IWCFAWRead
{
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(WCFAWRead));

    public PersonDetails getDetails(int entityID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (AWEntities ctx = new AWEntities())
            {
                var person = (from p in ctx.People
                              join det in ctx.Employees on p.BusinessEntityID equals det.BusinessEntityID
                              where p.BusinessEntityID == entityID
                              select new PersonDetails
                              {
                                  EntityID = p.BusinessEntityID,
                                  Name = p.FirstName,
                                  LastName = p.LastName,
                                  Title = det.JobTitle,
                                  BirthDay = det.BirthDate,
                                  Gender = det.Gender
                              }).FirstOrDefault();
                return person;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log.Error(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<FullPersonInfo> searchPerson(string chriteria)
    {
        try
        {
            using (AWEntities ctx = new AWEntities())
            {
                var lChriteria = chriteria.ToLower();
                var person = (from p in ctx.People
                              join det in ctx.Employees on p.BusinessEntityID equals det.BusinessEntityID
                              where p.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(lChriteria) || p.LastName.ToLower().Contains(lChriteria)
                              select new FullPersonInfo
                              {
                                  Person = p,
                                  Employee = det
                              }).ToList();
                return person;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log.Error(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

To cast the different types of Person object that is created from the wcf service reference, I use the following piece of code:

```
DataContractSerializer seri = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(AWReadReference.Person));
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("p.xml"))
            {
                seri.WriteObject(writer,person);
            }
            var deser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(AWCrudReference.Person));
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("p.xml"))
            {
                this.person = (AWCrudReference.Person)deser.ReadObject(reader);
            }
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is happening and a solution?

Comment: just curious why you're referring to it as "CRUD" and separate "READ" - the "R" in CRUD stands for "READ", so your class and interface name is somewhat misleading.

Comment: I got it, it is a lapsus. That service is dedicated for create, delete and update operations. Create and delete have not been created yet since I got stuck on the update part.

Comment: ah makes sense, just wanted to make sure :) can you point out and/or tag your specific version of entity framework, just in case it matters?

Comment: are you sure that your entity has all information associated to it?  specifically the key information?  Not seeing jumping out as wrong, so ensuring that your `Person` or `Employee` has the appropriate key would go a long way in making sure you're attaching to a valid entity

Comment: Usually this means that you're not writing to the database you expect. LocalDb, connection string?

Comment: that entity is retrieved from the db entirely, is it changed a couple of fields, and it is sent back to the wcf. I believe it do have all the information. All the properties are serialized and marked as datamembers, so they can be transmitted and used.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, it is connected to a local SQL server instance

Comment: Well, check executed SQL. If the code doesn't show any obvious errors (which it doesn't), there's really not much we can do about these kinds of problems.

Comment: yeah, you could debug your code and/or profile your database to ensure the code, and sql are what you would expect them to be.  The SQL will be a very good indicator as you'll be able to ensure it's hitting the correct DB, as well as checking what values are actually being passed to the DB.

Comment: I checked with sql profiler and nothing was sent in the db from ef during the update. Closed VS, restarted pc and started vs as administrator and now it is working. I am really surprised how can this happen! I was trying for a couple of hours and wasn't working.